# Importing database via IPython-SQL extension on Jupyter Notebook on Mac OS

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook

I keep getting an error for opening an existing database in Jupyter Notebook on my Macbook using the IPython-SQL extension

Hi all,

Usually, to open an existing database in Jupyter Notebook on Windows OS via IPython-SQL, this is how  the code goes:

```
%sql sqlite:///C:\Users\mandachan72\Documents\meow.db
```

I'm trying to do the same thing but with a Mac OS path (running on Mac of course), but I keep getting this error:

```
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection
```

Anyone with experience running IPython-SQL on Macbook? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you share the argument you're passing to the connection string? also, you ipython-sql is no longer maintainer so you might want to try JupySQL instead https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with sqllite on my mac, I don't think the OS is the issue, probably it's because you're trying to read a windows format path:

Windows:
`%sql sqlite:///C:\Users\mandachan72\Documents\meow.db`

Mac:
`%sql sqlite:///Users/mandachan72/Documents/meow.db`

[This SQLlite example](https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/intro.html) works on my MacOS as expected